# How to remove write permission of file using msi installer?

Tags: c#, winforms, installation

Iam using visual studio setup project (msi installer) for my winforms application. How to remove  write permission to c drive programefiles? How to implement file permission step by step in msi installer?

I tried cacls to remove file permission. But it is not works.

Answer (score 0):

The Program Files folder can be written to only with administrator privilege. That means you are asking how to prevent code that is running elevated (with admin privilege) from writing to files in the Program Files folder. It's not clear to me what access restrictions you need that to prevent elevated code from doing what elevated code is supposed to do because that's a security related issue, not an installer question.

The short answer to the design issue is that you should try to run your app with limited user privilege instead of administrator privilege, because limited users cannot write to files in the Program Files folder. However you haven't described the underlying problem you're trying to solve, you've just asked how to implement your proposed solution.

If cacls didn't work, it's impossible to say if it will never work (because you are doing a Just me install, as an example) or if you had an implementation error (because you wrote some kind of custom action to do it and your code is incorrect). The general answer to all these types of question is "write a custom action", but without details of exactly what you tried it's impossible to know why it didn't work, but that's the answer, and if a custom action doesn't work then it's a design or coding problem that requires showing the code and saying if it's an Everyone or Just me install.